# calling a Covariant method in Scala

Tags: scala, covariance

I have a class

```
class Getable [+T] (val data: T)
```

And I create a method for the class to print the Number

```
def printNumber (in: Getable[Number]) = { println("It's " + in.data)}
```

So it works for

```
get(new Getable(10.0))
```

But does not work for

```
val g = new Getable(10.0)
get(g)
```

I get this error message

```
scala> get(g)
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
found   : Getable[Double]
required: Getable[Number]
   get(g)
       ^
```

But overcoming the error message is the reason why we use covariance.

Comment: In Scala `Number` is not a supertype of `scala.Double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to hint a compiler with a type of `Getable`.

`val g: Getable[Number] = new Getable(10.0)`

or

`val g = new Getable[Number](10.0)`

Comment: OP is asking specifically about contravariance. Your approach would work with an invariant declaration as well and thus does not leverage variance.